# Haskell: takeWhile on list of Maybe

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads

An infinite list of `Maybe n`, which, from a specific position, has only `Nothing` items:

```
someNumbers :: [Maybe Int]
someNumbers = [Just 4, Just 3, Just 2, Just 1] ++ cycle [Nothing]
```

I would like to count the `n`s statisfying a predicate `p`, stopping at the first `Nothing`:

```
howMany :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Maybe Int] -> Int
```

This is what I came up with, with explicit recursion:

```
howMany p ((Just n):rest)
| p n = 1 + (howMany p rest)
| otherwise = 0
howMany _ _ = 0
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to express this, making use of advanced Haskell abstractions.

Comment: Why not just do `takeWhile isJust`, then count after?

Comment: How would you apply the predicate and count inside the list of `Maybe` in an elegant way, without matching on the `Just` constructor?

Comment: Filter out the Nothings, then fold over the resulting list, unwrapping the justs, and counting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would work.

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust, maybe)
howMany p = length . filter (maybe False p) . takeWhile isJust
```

Or alternatively you could also use `fromJust` instead of `maybe`. Normally partial functions like `fromJust` are discouraged, however in this case it is safe.

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust)
howMany p = length . filter (p . fromJust) . takeWhile isJust
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LuigiSgro This function can be written even shorter:

`howMany p = length . takeWhile (maybe False p)`

Comment: But that function doesn't do the same. It counts just the first elements, that  are not Nothing and satisfy `p`. The question asked for a function, that counts the number of elements satisfying `p` out of the first elements, that are not Nothing.

Comment: @jpath Hmm.. You're right. Didn't think about this. Well, I guess I can't write shorter :(